# How to ignore the list of files show in a Commit

Tags: git, bitbucket, egit, jgit

I just Imported the project from Bitbucket(GIT) into Eclipse. It worked fine. When i request to Pull again it says everything is up to date.

But if i try to commit the same project even without changing anything in the code it tries to commit everything back. As i believe they should not appear in a commit since they havent been changed. How to mark them they are not changed.

Comment: Could you add a trace? What does `git status` return right after the pull?

Comment: Sorry I have mentioned the question bit wrong. For the first time i pull the project through "import project" wizard. So i believe what happens is cloning of the project

Comment: Ok, then I guess you should try the different tools in Eclipse, via right-click -> Team, like determine if the files are source-controlled (if Git is trying to commit .project, uncheck the box), or to compare to previous version. I don't really use it so I don't really know more